# store and use arbitrary method arguments in php

Tags: php

I am storing jobs in a table that a process picks up and executes later.
The way I store the jobs now (among others) are:

> $className, $method, $params

where params is a JSON encoded array. Now I am executing the jobs like this:

```
$params = Zend_Json_Decoder::decode($params);    
$cM = new $clname ();
$result = $cM->$method ( $params );
```

The problem is that different methods expect parameters in different formats - some expect a set number of scalars, some an array, some mixed.

How should I package and unpackage the parameters so that they could be arguments to any methods?
Or should I do this in a completely different way?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: `serialize()` and `unserialize()`? It's slightly more efficient than JSON encoding it if you're not passing data between PHP and JavaScript. Also, see: func_get_args - http://uk.php.net/func_get_args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your existing storage method, and call the routines using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$params = Zend_Json_Decoder::decode($params);    
$cM = new $clname();
$result = call_user_func_array(array($cM, $method), $params);
```

Only disadvantage is that it does start to get complicated when the method in question expects an argument to be passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try code evaluation. I think this shoukd fix your problem.

```
$params = Zend_Json_Decoder::decode($params);
$params_str = "";
$params_first = true;
foreach (array_keys($params) as $param) {
   $params_str .= (($params_first) ? "" : ",") . " \$params[$param]";
   $params_first = false;
}
$cM = new $clname ();
eval("\$result = \$cM->$method ( $params_str );");
```